Google Ads: How to Remove Call Goal?
Google Ad Manager is giving me this message:

Call extension is missing
You have a call goal without a call extension. Your campaign may not be properly optimized. Add a call extension to use with your ads.

Now, I don't want people to call a phone number. I want them to visit the website. So I go to the Goals Summary page and click "Remove" for the "Calls from Smart Campaign Ads" goal.

I see a toast saying "Failed to Remove Conversion Types".

How can I fix this?
